# Making stubbornly hidden tray icons visible again

Tags: windows-10

Anyone know of a software tool or other trick that will rescan your system tray icons and make them visible again? you know when explorer crashed or something like that and some programs that are running are not showing their tray icons any longer? (and if you run that program again it still doesn't help since it is still running but if you reboot they will be visible again)

Comment: Is there a particular application or applications you're more worried about?  I would consider just having a batch file that kills the process responsible for tray icon(s) you care about and relaunch the process.  You shouldn't need to reboot/log-off/on.  First step is identifying the process name responsible for the notification tray icons.   Windows doesn't make this mapping that easy to establish, I'd suggest using Process Explorer and AutoRuns from Microsoft to work it out.  A simple taskkill command for the process name and then re-launch it using the established path.

Comment: when this seems to happen, it happens to several applications. One is RoboTask lite. Sure I could kill them individually but I was thinking there might be any easier way to refresh all the icons. Restarting explorer doesn't help.

Comment: The problem is, the behaviour depends on how each application is written and their use of the function Shell_NotifyIcon, i.e when they add, modify, delete. You can imagine that most tray icon processes call "add" at startup but then probably don't go on to monitor "If they are visible" by some means.  If Explorer crashes it has no reference of the tray icons that previously added themselves for the last session so it relies on the process going through it's startup process again to "add" the icon to the tray hence restarting them almost always helps.

Comment: I'm not aware of an easy way (supported APIs) from a script to enumerate the icons in the tray to obtain the process path that backs them.  This "good" data (maybe gathered shortly after startup) could then be used by a script to know what should be present and kill/re-launch them even if you manually kick off the recovery when you notice them missing.

Comment: ok, thanks - well i thought it was worth asking anyhow since I had no luck with google

Comment: This might be the most useful page - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114887/can-i-re-gain-a-systray-icon-of-a-running-app-that-has-gone-missing

Answer (score 0):

Does this help at all?  You can turn the icons on or off here.

[image: Select incons appear]

Comment: no, the icon doesn't show anywhere - not even if you click the upside down V on the taskbar, I think there is no real solution apart from what the other person suggested about killing problem tasks individually one-by-one